# Distinct command doesn't work

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, distinct

This is the command:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.TRIP_ID, T.TRIP_NAME, T.STATE, T.TYPE, S.TRIP_ID, S.TRIP_NAME

FROM TRIP T, TRIP S

WHERE T.STATE = 'NH'

AND T.TYPE = 'Hiking'

AND T.TRIP_ID < S.TRIP_ID

ORDER BY T.TRIP_NAME;
```

I should only getting about 6 results but somehow I get 298 repeated results. What's the problem with this code?

Correct result (6 entries)

[image: Correct result]

My result (first few entries) which totals to 298 entries

[image]

Comment: Could you share the some sample data, the result you're trying to get for it, and the result you actually get?

Comment: @Mureinik Just added the results, hope it's enough!

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Doesn't that question talk about the code itself? (which I have listed as text) The only images I have are of the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing a self join in this example. But if you want just the distinct trip names in New Hampshire that involved hiking, do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T.TRIP_NAME
FROM TRIP T
WHERE T.STATE = 'NH' AND T.TYPE = 'Hiking' 
ORDER BY T.TRIP_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

THE DISTINCT keyword operates on ALL select-list items that follow it, not just the next immediate column.  So, in your case, it IS (or would be) removing duplicates when ALL columns are considered.  The results you show all look individual over all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

you have a missing join condition by usual convention.